# How successful was the French Initiative for Western Balkans?

Tags: european-union, france

I'm trying to write an essay about the "French Initiative for Western Balkans" and the consequent results of their new methodology. It has been 4 years since the process started and there is no progress in terms of a country from the said region joining the EU, so it has not been easy to name the main things that French Administration did regarding the matter.

I'm mostly interested in how good was French Initiative in terms of fulfilling goals it set?

Feel free to provide any sources that may help me in understanding current state of things.

Comment: French Imitative? What are you referring to? If you are asking people to provide you information to do what sounds like your homework you should provide as many details as possible.

Comment: There have been lots of French initiatives in the Westen Balkans, some of them successful, some not. I found none that was publicized under the name "French Initiative for Western Balkans". Which are you referring to?